# Building an array of deferred functions (promises)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm learning promises and I'm trying, in this example, to create an array of promises which I can execute (under **native ES6**) with Promise.all(...).

The promises should "launch" a function which doubles the number passed to it.
I expected the execution of the promises would be deferred until I had called Promises.all(), but the results are printed immediately. What am I missing??

I want the promises to start when I call them and not as soon as possible (if it wasn't clear)

```
 var buildPromises = function(numbers) {
    var res = [];
     numbers.forEach(function(num) {
         var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
             console.log(num * 2);
         });
         res.push(p);
     });
     return res;
 }

 var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
 var p = buildPromises(numbers);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The promise executor function (the callback you pass to `new Promise()`) is designed to be executed immediately, thus you will see all your `console.log()` statements immediately.

What usually happens in the executor is that you start some async operation such as an ajax request or an async file I/O request and then some time later, that request will call `resolve(xxx)` to resolve that promise with a value.  What you have now has no async operations, never calls `resolve()` and really should not be using promises at all since there is no asynchronous activity here.

A promise is not a function.  It is not "executed".  So, you don't really create an array of deferred functions with promises like your question implies.  You could use promises to keep track of some asynchronous operations and you could execute some functions when those promises resolved by attaching listeners to the promise, but you don't really execute promises.

To make a promise that you're creating work, you supply the function that executes as the promise executor callback passed to `new Promise(fn)`.  That's where the executing happens.  The promise itself is just an object that serves as a placeholder for a future value of some asynchronous operation.  The promise value is set when code in the executor calls `resolve(someValue)`.  Or, an error can be indicated by calling `reject(someError)`.  Meanwhile code outside the executor function can then register listeners with `.then()` or `.catch()` to listen for a state change in the promise (some future time when the promise fulfills to a value or ends with an error).

So, right after either `resolve()` or `reject()` is called, the appropriate event listeners (that were registered with `.then()` or with `.catch()`) will trigger, informing the listening code that there is finally a resolution to this promise (either a value or an error).  That listening code can then process that value or error.

`Promise.all()` accepts an array of promises and returns a new master promise that is rejected when any of the array of promises rejects or is resolved with an array of values when all the array of promises are resolved.  It watches all those other promises and essentially gives you a summary of them all.

To simulate an async operation, we could put all your operations inside a `setTimeout()` and then call `resolve()` like this runnable snippet:

```js
 var buildPromises = function (numbers) {
     var res = [];
     numbers.forEach(function (num) {
         var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
             // this is called immediately and it starts
             // an asynchronous operation that will finish later
             setTimeout(function () {
                 var result = num * 2;
                 console.log("individual:", result);
                 // resolve the promise with our result
                 resolve(result);
             }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 500);
         });
         res.push(p);
     });
     return Promise.all(res);
 }

 var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 buildPromises(numbers).then(function (results) {
     console.log("group: ", JSON.stringify(results));
 });
```

In the results here after running this snippet, notice that the individual `console.log()` statements may be in any order (since async operations are usually unpredictable in timing), but the `Promise.all()` group results are always kept in the original order of the promises in the array.  That is another service that `Promise.all()` provides.

---

Also, it saves code to use `.map()` to build your array of promises since you're traversing an array and building a new array with one promise per element which is exactly what `.map()` was designed for.  You can do that like this:

```js
var buildPromises = function (numbers) {
    return Promise.all(numbers.map(function (num) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var result = num * 2;
                console.log("individual:", result);
                resolve(result);
            }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 500);
        });
    }));
}

var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
buildPromises(numbers).then(function (results) {
     console.log("group: ", JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

Comment: +1 Making the timeout `Math.random() * 1000` would demonstrate the purpose of promises even clearer, I think.

Comment: @lonesomeday - Agreed.  I made the timeout be random.

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is that Promise is **the result of an action** and *not* an action itself. A Promise is merely an object you can hold on to now, while you wait for the value in the future.

The action will be performed as soon as you call the function which returns the Promise. If you want to delay that, delay calling the function.